# Delphi 2009 refactoring error

Tags: delphi, refactoring, delphi-2009

I use Delphi2009. When using Refactoring -> Change Params every time when I try to add new parameter to routine, when I setup new parameter and click “Refactor” I get an error:

[alt text http://img518.imageshack.us/img518/6672/delphief.jpg](http://img518.imageshack.us/img518/6672/delphief.jpg)

(NOTE: imageshack sometimes has problems, so sometimes you may not see this image).

Do you know any workaround?

Comment: You mean details from this window? Beacause when it comes to source code, it is no matter what I try to refactor - every adding parameters to any procedure crashes.

Comment: Do you have all updates installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the case.

This error occurs only if file in which we perform refactoring is not in USES section of DPR file ie. is a library file in Delphi’s search path (or how is this path called).

Answer (score 0):

Looking naively at that callstack, have you checked if everything related to debugging symbols is *on* in your compiler options?

Comment: @Paul-Jan: does refactoring tools use the debug info at any level?

Comment: I don't expect it to, I was just going on the _GetSymbolInformation_ in the callstack. A long shot, and apparently completely off target.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message, since there is some problem with screenshot hosting site.

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Borland.Studio.Delphi.ChangeParamsRefactoring.GetSymbolInformation(String& namespaceName, String& oldParamSig, String& newParamSig, String& symbolKind, String& returnSig, String& containingUnit, String& project, String& outputName, String& personality)
   at Borland.Studio.Refactoring.BaseChangeParamsRefactoring.GetRefactoringNode()
   at Borland.Studio.Refactoring.BaseRefactoring.f()
   at Borland.Studio.Interop.StatusForm.a(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnActivated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Active(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmActivate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Interop
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Interop.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Together
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Together.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.InternalAPI
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.InternalAPI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Core
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Build.Tasks.Common
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.Globalization
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Globalization.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
vbgadrhp
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.ToolsAPI
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.ToolsAPI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Host
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Host.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Design
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Design/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Build.Framework
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 built by: netfxsp
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Build.Framework/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Refactoring
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Refactoring.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.OpenAPI3
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.OpenAPI3.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.SCI2
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.SCI2.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.VFS
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.VFS.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Actions
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Actions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.SCI.Impl
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.SCI.Impl.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.JSCI
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.JSCI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.ModelView
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.ModelView.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.ClassBrowser
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.ClassBrowser.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Model3
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Model3.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.DesignModel
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.DesignModel.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Refactoring.Plugins.UI
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Refactoring.Plugins.UI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Diagram.Core
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Diagram.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Diagram.Basics
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Diagram.Basics.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.ModelPerformers
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.ModelPerformers.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.CoreResources
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.CoreResources.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Refactoring.Plugins
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Refactoring.Plugins.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Refactoring.API
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Refactoring.API.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Refactoring.Platform
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Refactoring.Platform.DLL
----------------------------------------
vjslib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/vjslib/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/vjslib.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.DrawingSurface
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.DrawingSurface.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.DiagramClass
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.DiagramClass.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.DiagramExtensions
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.DiagramExtensions.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.ModelBasics
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.ModelBasics.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.SCI.Impl.Delphi
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.SCI.Impl.Delphi.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.LanguageSupport.Delphi
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.LanguageSupport.Delphi.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.UMLDiagrams1x
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.UMLDiagrams1x.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.SCI.Impl.MSIL
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.SCI.Impl.MSIL.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.LanguageSupport.MSIL
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.LanguageSupport.MSIL.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.DiagramInteraction
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.DiagramInteraction.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.UMLDiagrams20
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.UMLDiagrams20.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.HyperLinks
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.HyperLinks.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Ocl.Model
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Ocl.Model.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.Refactoring.Manager
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.Refactoring.Manager.DLL
----------------------------------------
vjscor
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/vjscor/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/vjscor.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.Together.XMLExport
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Together.XMLExport.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Delphi
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Delphi.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Delphi.Gate
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Delphi.Gate.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Studio.Vcl.Design.Refactoring
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/CodeGear/RAD%20Studio/6.0/bin/Borland.Studio.Vcl.Design.Refactoring.DLL
----------------------------------------
Borland.Delphi
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Borland.Delphi/12.0.0.0__91d62ebb5b0d1b1b/Borland.Delphi.dll
----------------------------------------
Borland.VclRtl
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Borland.VclRtl/12.0.0.0__91d62ebb5b0d1b1b/Borland.VclRtl.dll
----------------------------------------
DelphiProvider
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.3420.21218
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/DelphiProvider/12.0.0.0__91d62ebb5b0d1b1b/DelphiProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Build.Engine
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 built by: netfxsp
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Build.Engine/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Build.Utilities
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 built by: netfxsp
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Build.Utilities/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Build.Tasks
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 built by: netfxsp
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.SqlXml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.SqlXml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.SqlXml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```